# php Illegal string offset

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems with outputting my array. Basically, some documents and additional info are being uploaded to database, and i would like to display download link and that uploaded details (onclick) about them afterwards.
This is my code:

```
$sqlresult = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT u.username, p.p_url FROM users AS u INNER JOIN papers AS p ON p.user_id = u.user_id WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['user']}'");
$check_row = mysql_num_rows($sqlresult);
$counter = 1;
$output = "";
$outarray = array();
if ($check_row > 0) {
  while ($output = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {
    $outarray[1] = $output[1];
    if (is_array($outarray)) {
      foreach ($outarray as $val) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT p_name, p_authors, p_corresponding, p_email, p_cauthor, p_abstract, p_jname, p_date FROM papers INNER JOIN users ON papers.user_id = users.user_id WHERE p_url = '$val' AND username='{$_SESSION['user']}'");
        $last = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        foreach ($last as $key => $value){
          // echo "$key"."=="."$value";
          $search = substr($val, 0, strpos($val, '.'));
          $trim = str_replace($val, '', $search);
          $counter++;
        }
      }
      echo <<<HERE
      <a href="http://localhost:8080/laboratory/users/{$_SESSION['user']}/{$val}" target="_blank">{$trim}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#collapse{$counter}" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; " onclick="$('p').show();return false;" class="nav-toggle">+ See details</a>

      <div id="collapse{$counter}" style="display:none">
      <p>Name:{$value['p_name']}, Author:{$value['p_authors']}, Corresponding author:{$value['p_corresponding']}, etc ...</p>
      </div>  
      <br />
      HERE;
    }
  }
} else {                           
  echo "You don't have any papers uploaded !";
}
}
}
```

And i got warning: "Warning: Illegal string offset", but how is that possible when second foreach loop gives proper output (commented echo part) ? Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: To make things easier for potential helpers, try to create a minimal, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What line triggers the warning?

Comment: echo part, div id with counter, section in paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: strpos will return FALSE if '.' is not found in $val. When using FALSE in substr the warning is triggered.

Comment: Fair enough, but im not sure it causes aforementioned error